# Return value from shell script without using echo

Tags: c++, linux, bash

I have c++ code which includes a [system](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) call which in turn calls a bash oneliner

```c
if (system("if [ `ls | wc -l` -eq 1 ]; then return 0 ; else return 1; fi") != 0)
    std::cout << "returned non zero" << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << "returned zero" << std::endl;
```

This doesn't work since I get this error

```
-bash: return: can only `return' from a function or sourced script
```

If I use `echo` instead of return I get the return code of the `echo` command instead the value passed to `echo`. Any idea how to go around this?

Comment: It would be far simpler to just open the current working directory in C++ than to shell out to `bash` to launch yet more programs.

Comment: This code is just to demonstrate my problem, the "if" statement in my system call is much more complex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need return, just change your code to this:

```
if ( system( "[ `ls | wc -l` -eq 1 ]" ) != 0)
    std::cout << "returned non zero" << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << "returned zero" << std::endl;
```

This code:

```
[ `ls | wc -l` -eq 1 ]
```

will return 0 or 1 as per the condition and `system` will return that status to your C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `exit 0` and `exit 1` in your bash command. Note that 0 typically means success, while non-0 means there was some error.